# Find p(0) if...

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

*Question*
If $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $p(x)-p'(x)=x^n$ where n is a positive integer,find the value of p(0)

Options 
(A) $n!$
(B) $(n-1)!$
(C) $1/n!$
(D) $1/(n-1)!$

*My approach*
I started solving the question by assuming $p(x)=a0+a1•x^1+a2•x^2+.....+an•x^n$ and
$p'(x)=a1+2•a2•x+3•a3•x^2+.....+n•an•(x^{(n-1)})$

So then
$p(x)-p'(x)=a0+a1(x^1-1)+a2(x^2-2x)+.....+an(x^n-nx^{(n-1)})
=x^n$

Now I can't quite understand what to do.any help is appreciated.Thanks :)

*EDIT*
I tried taking the x terms common so I get
$p(x)-p'(x)=a0-a1+x(a1-2•a2)+x^2(a2-3•a3)+.....+x^{n-1}(a(n-1)-n•an)+an•x^n=x^n$

So $p(0)=a0-a1$
Now I still don't understand how the answer is in terms of n

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try taking the expression you got for $p(x) - p'(x)$ (which I can confirm is correct), and rearranging it to combine terms with like powers of $x$. (So the constant term is $a_0 - a_1$, the coefficient of $x$ is $a_1 - 2a_2$, and so on.)

Once you've done that, you can figure out what has to be true about $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n$ for this to be the same polynomial as $x^n$.